# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting question

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

So I have it set that if a cell has a value of 0 to change the background to yellow. I want to have it so that if there are two 0's (zeros) next to each other in a row (edit: in adjoining cells not within the same cell) that it'll turn red (but not if there are two zeros in the row but separated by a value, only if they're beside each other). 
I've tried searching but the other questions I found are different and I was struggling to adapt their solutions to my problem.

Edited to add image of what I want it to look like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need 2 rules to achieve your results.
The 1st one -as you already mentioned- is **`Text contains 0`**
The 2nd is very similar to your 1st one **`Text contains 00`**

#### **Filters must be in the correct order**

[image: correct]

#### **Filters in the wrong order give you wrong results**

[image: very wrong]

Comment: No, not consecutive zeros in the same cell but in adjoining cells.

Comment: Please do share a link to a sample sheet  along with the desired solution to better understand your needs.